# What does "numbers game" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I use this link but don't quite understand it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numbers_game
What does the author imply here?
"What separates and sets apart these 18 emerging market economies from the rest? For some, it’s a numbers game, as they started to grow at extremely low levels. Yet for some, there are four specific policies, according to the same study, which contribute."

Source:https://www.forbes.com/sites/panosmourdoukoutas/2018/10/01/18-emerging-economies-lifted-a-billion-people-out-of-extreme-poverty-what-they-did-right/#6d062ebc4c84

Answer (score 1):

Idioms can be used for so long that their meaning drifts when people do not understand the origin of the term. A numbers game is a lottery. However, gambling is the opposite of a sure thing – unless you are the one running the lottery.

The idiom refers to the way [betting syndicates are able to rig a lottery through strategic mass-betting that shifts the odds in their favor](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2016/02/how-mit-students-gamed-the-lottery/470349/). This *betting syndicate* will still lose individual games, but over time their strategy puts them ahead of the casual player. In the long run they are assured to make money.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_Schultz#The_Numbers_Game

In a business context, the idiom means using a strategy of long-game mathematics to eventually come out ahead: making more cold calls will inevitably lead to more sales (mass betting), or buying real estate and sitting on the properties until the neighborhood's value increases (long game).